# Segmentation Fault 11 when running Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault

I have just updated to the newest Xcode 6.3 beta and I am receiving an error that I can't figure out the solution to.

When I run my app, I am getting the error: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault 11`. I had a look through the full error message and I have taken the parts out that I think are relevant:

```
(unresolved_dot_expr type='@lvalue String!' location=/Filename/FifthViewController.swift:423:19 range=[/Filename/FifthViewController.swift:423:9 - line:423:19] field 'text'
  (declref_expr type='UITextField' location=/Filename/FifthViewController.swift:423:9 range=[/Filename/FifthViewController.swift:423:9 - line:423:9] decl=AffordIt.(file).FifthViewController.func decl.textField@/Filename/FifthViewController.swift:418:34 specialized=yes))
```

And

```
While emitting SIL for 'textFieldDidChangeValue' at /Filename/FifthViewController.swift:418:5
```

Anyone have any ideas? Obviously I've replaced the full path with 'Filename'. This is the code related to the error:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChangeValue:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChangeValue(textField: UITextField) {
    //Automatic formatting for transaction value text field. Target is added above.
    var text = textField.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol!, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator!, withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") // There is a special character here. This line is critical for european/other currencies.
    println(textField.text)

    textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
    currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
    valueEnter.alpha = 1
}
```

Here is the initialisation of currencyFormatter:

```
    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

    if let currencyCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode) as? String {
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems, the problem is in this line:

```
textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
```

It must be a compiler bug. The workarounds I found are:

```
// Explicitly cast as `NSNumber`
textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0 as NSNumber)

// or explicitly construct `NSNumber` from `Double` 
textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0))

// or prepare `Double` outside
let doubleVal = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(doubleVal)

// or convert `String` to `Double` without casting to `NSString`.
textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber( atof(text) / 100.0)
```

The minimum code that reproduces this problem would be:

```
let str = "42"
let a:NSNumber = (str as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
```

Swift 1.1/Xcode 6.1.1 compiles it successfully, but Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 Beta2 crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long shot, but how is your `currencyFormatter` declared? Is it marked with an `!` and not intialised? I used the following code to test for a faulty declaration and it behaved rather strangely in my Swift iOS Playground:

```
var myTextField = UITextField()
var currencyFormatter : NSNumberFormatter!  // Possible offender! Not initiliased, and forcefully unwrapped!!!

func myFunc(textField: UITextField) {
    //Automatic formatting for transaction value text field. Target is added above.
    var text : String = textField.text // Error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION


    //if currencyFormatter !=  nil {
        text = textField.text
           .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.currencySymbol!, withString: "")
           .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, withString: "")
           .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator!, withString: "")
           .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") // There is a special character here. This line is critical for european/other currencies.

           println("original: \(textField.text), after replacing: \(text)")
           textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber((text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0)
           println("new: \(textField.text)")

           // currencyDouble = (text as NSString).doubleValue / 100.0
           // valueEnter.alpha = 1
     // } else {
     //    println("No currencyFormatter")
     // }

}

//currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
// Uncomment line above, and the playground failed on second line in myFunc()
myTextField.text = "$123.000,00"

myFunc(myTextField)
myTextField.text
```

If this is your case as well, you need to look into the missing initialisation of the `currencyFormatter`, and also uncomment the `if` statements from my code excerpt to avoid it crashing everything. If uncommenting, you'll also see if this is the actual error case for you as there is an `else` clause stating that the `currencyFormatter` actually is `nil`.

The reason for me looking into this case, was to see if you had a problem with unwrapping of `currencyFormatter.currencySymbol!` and `currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator!`, but testing revealed they could be `nil` without casing any other issue than `text == ""`.

You might also want to look into the `NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString()` method, see following:

```
var currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

if let numberStr = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: 123567.45)) {

    if let number = currencyFormatter.numberFromString(numberStr) {
        println("numberStr = \(numberStr) vs number = \( number )")
    }
}
```

which outputs `numberStr = $123,567.45 vs number = 123567.45` after converting back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll have a look at the things you suggested a little later. I have edited my question with the initialisation of 'currencyFormatter'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here and it was not related to the code itself. all of them disappeared after upgrading to Xcode 6.3 beta 2 released by Apple two days ago. give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately, I have just updated to Xcode 6.3 beta 2 from Xcode 6.1.